# React: TextField onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of data that lists on the collapse, I just want to display in my collapse what i put on my Textfield

```
const onChangeLocation = (locations) =>{
    console.log(locations)
  }

   <TextField
      size="small"
      fullWidth
      onChange={onChangeLocation}
      variant="standard"
      placeholder="Search Locations"
      onFocus={openSearch}
      value={searchParameter}
      }}
    />

  <Collapse in={viewLocationList} sx={{ my: '2px' }}>
    <Box className="rounded-scrollbar widget-result-container">
      {locations.map((location, index) => (
        <LocationWidgetItem
          key={index}
          location={location}
          onClickLocation={setActiveLocation}
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the state to store the location you are getting from textfield? If not please use the state to store the input you get from textfield into a state like this -

```
const [location, setLocation] = useState('')

const onChangeLocation = (event) => {
 setLocation(event.target.value)
}

<TextField
  size="small"
  fullWidth
  onChange={onChangeLocation}
  variant="standard"
  placeholder="Search Locations"
  onFocus={openSearch}
  value={location}
  }}
 />

  <Collapse in={viewLocationList} sx={{ my: '2px' }}>
    <Box className="rounded-scrollbar widget-result-container">
      {locations.map((location, index) => (
        <LocationWidgetItem
          key={index}
          location={location}
          onClickLocation={setActiveLocation}
        />
      ))}
    </Box>
  </Collapse>
```

If you are using the state to store the location then too you can use the code above. Your code was not working because you are not sending the param from your textfield and the function `onChangeLocation` is expecting an argument which it isn't getting so it should be returning undefined.

Comment: hello, i type on the textfield but no letter display

Comment: Did you add a console log statement inside the on-change function? If so let me know what the event.target.value is returning.

Comment: yes i add it, i can see what i type on console but not in the textfield

Comment: I have edited the answer above. For the value on the textfield use location which is being stored in the state.